# Magento - Allow user to manage social media URLs

Tags: magento

Ok so I’m trying to implement social media into the footer. However, they are images that change color when hovered over that I’m working into the CSS. 
But my question is, if the end user changed their Facebook URL, how will they update the url? I obviously can’t just put it directly into the theme because then the end-user will know how to program and where to look just to change the URL. 
How do I go about implementing this the right way so the end-user can update their social media URLs to their Facebook/Twitter/YouTube/Etc easily..?

Comment: By 'user', do you mean administrator or customer?

Comment: Whoever is the owner of the store and needs to update their store.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by saying "user changed their Facebook URL"?

You talking about customer or administrator?

If you mean administrator, then the you can create custom settings for social media links

For customers store theirs social uids

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you will need to create an extension, albeit not a very complicated one. If you've never done this before, Alan storm wrote an [excellent tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento).

One file that is often included in extensions (but seems not to be mentioned in the above mentioned tutorial) is `etc/system.xml`. This file lets you define a new page in the `System->Configuration` section of the Magento admin panel. Magento provides a [good tutorial on writing those](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/admin/xml_structure_for_admin_configurations).

Any fields you put in `etc/system.xml` will be modifiable in the Magento admin panel, and you can access them anywhere in your code with `Mage::getStoreConfig('`your extension's name`/`the name of the field`')`, e.g., `Mage::getStoreConfig('facebook/enabled');`

Comment: I don't see the second paragraph you typed anywhere in that tutorial :/ So you can customize the admin panel and add another section where they can change the URLs of their social media?

Comment: I edited my answer to include a link to a different tutorial on `system.xml` files. They let you define fields in the Magento backend that users can change and that programmers can access directly from code.